# What does the usage of "under" in this context mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, errors

What does *under* mean here, how do you define it?

From a biography:

> Shum graduated from Arroyo Grande High School in 2000. He started
>   dancing with his high school dance company team and continued his
>   career in San Francisco under several different studios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Under the tutelage of"; "being taught by"; or possibly "as part of the professional company associated with". For another example, you could say that a novice artist *studies under* (i.e., *is taught by*) a master artist.

"Shum studied under such-and-such *studio*" (as opposed to such-and-such *teacher*) doesn't seem quite right to me, but the meaning is clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

The ordinary English idioms are:

- One studies *under* a master artist or craftsman; it’s a metaphor drawn from the old guild system in arts and scholarship, where an apprentice or student put himself *under* the master’s discipline.
- One studies *in* or *at* the studio which the master directs.

COCA gives no examples of studying *under a studio*.  Google yields 105 instances of *under the studio of*, mostly referring to artists artists and productions “under” a film, recording or animation studio. Eliminating duplicates leaves 21 unique uses. Of these:

- Four occur in student biographies of pre-20th-century painters
- One occurs in the biography of a floristry instructor
- One occurs in the resume of a high-school dancer
- One occurs in the self-written biography of a Russian jazz musician
- 14 occur in program-style biographies of musicians, all of East Asian origin.

I have no hesitation in pronouncing “under the studio of” a mistake by persons unfamiliar with the accepted idiom.

Answer (score 0):

Per the OED:

> **III.** In senses implying that one thing is covered by, or included in, another.
>
> **18**. With words denoting protection, care, or benevolent interest. See also ***auspice***<sup>3</sup>, ***protection***<sup>1b</sup>.